# UNIX approach to capturing video from webcam across a network

Tags: linux, networking, webcam, pipe

I have two Linux computers on a LAN (call them Foo and Bar), and I'd like to find a way to capture stream video from the webcam on Foo to Bar.

I'd like to avoid using a GUI client which uses a complex network protocol, like Telepathy, which uses XMPP, or Skype, which uses a proprietary protocol, and I feel like there's probably a nice, simple, UNIX-oriented approach using the command-line and pipes, like `bar$ ssh Foo "cat /dev/video0" > stream.avi`.

Maybe I need to use the gstreamer command-line tool. I'd appreciate any guidance anyone can offer on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not quite UNIX, [VLC](http://www.videolan.org) should be able to do this, judging from [its wiki](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples) and from [its documentation](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch10.html).

Comment: Seems like a good approach. I found another article which also describes how to do this: http://scottlinux.com/2010/06/29/stream-webcam-with-vlc/